# Showing a 3D diagram in R

Tags: r, 3d

I want to show information in 3D. I am reading values from a file, line by line, saving these values in a list:

```
point<-10
spalte<-500
for(i in 1:point)
{
  line<-readLines(con,n=1,warn=FALSE)
  m<-list(as.integer(unlist(strsplit(line,split=","))))
  datalist<-c(datalist,sapply(m,"[[",spalte))
}
```

`point` indicates how many values should be read, `Spalte` indicates which column is to be read. My file has 10000 rows and 7500 columns.

I then calculate the amplitude for each value :

```
fft_amplitude <- function(x) {sqrt((Re(fft(x)))^2+(Im(fft(x)))^2)}
df<-matrix(unlist(datalist,use.names=FALSE),ncol=1,byrow=TRUE)
r<-apply(df,2,FUN=fft_amplitude)
```

In this situation I can use 2D diagram:

```
plot(r[1:(point/2)],pch=20,ylim=c(0,20000),xlim=c(0,point),cex=0.9,ylab="amplitude",xlab="Frequenz")
```

but I want to show this information in 3 dimensions (time, frequency, and amplitude). I create my 3D diagram with:

```
x<-1:length(datalist)
y<-1:length(datalist)
z<-matrix(unlist(datalist,use.names=FALSE),ncol=length(datalist),nrow=length(datalist),byrow=TRUE)
z<-apply(z,2,FUN=fft_amplitude)
persp(x,y,z,theta = 30, phi = 40, expand = 0.5, col = "lightblue")
```

This code displays a 3 dimensional diagram, but the result is different than the two dimensional diagram. How can I show my data in 3D?

**Update**

I think that I should explain my problem simpler:

I want to have a 3D diagramm. My Information are:

- x:Time   ----- it could be 1:n (integer number)
- Y:Frequency ---it could be 1:n like x
- z:the value of z come from a function:

  fft_amplitude <- function(x) {sqrt((Re(fft(x)))^2+(Im(fft(x)))^2)}

the input value for this function should be read from a CSV file. How can I draw a 3D diagram `persp`with this infos?

Comment: Your question is unclear: do you want something like `image(z)`, `persp(z)`, `rgl::persp3d(z)`?

Comment: Yes, `persp(x,y,z)` would be ideal

Comment: Could the problem be a result of the 2nd to last line `z<-apply(...`? Looks like your object `z`would no longer be a matrix, thus making it inappropriate for `persp()`.

Comment: It is a matrix but with only one column

Comment: Yes but it's dimensions should be dim(z) == c(length(x), length(y)) for `persp` - I'm surprised it plots anything at all. You might be looking for a scatter plot, such as in package `lattice` function `cloud()`.